# how to get cookie in template webpy

Tags: python, web.py

How do I get the cookie in the `index.html` template:

```
render = web.template.render('templates/', base='layout', cache=False)
```

Comment: What do you mean `get cookie`?

Comment: yes! like this `layout.html $def with(cookies) $cookies.get('someattr')` but now I can't get the cooikes.

Comment: Look here: http://webpy.org/cookbook/cookies. You might have to pass `cookies` as a parameter.

Comment: layout is html document, I meaning how to get the cookies use webpy template language. could you give me a example code ? thanks

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Web.py, but can't you send variables to the template when rendering it? If so, send a `cookies` variable with the cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import web
template_globals = {
    "cookies": web.cookies,
}
render = web.template.render('templates/', globals=template_globals, base='layout', cache=False)
```

You can also do things like this:

```
render_partial = web.template.render('templates/', globals=template_globals)
template_globals.update(render=render_partial)
```

And then you will be able to render partial templates in your templates